# How can I achieve this Flash effect using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

**UPDATE:** The effects work fine. **The last thing that remains is trying to slide trough the divs whic I can't seem to be able to [figure out](http://www.sopranowebdesign.com/animation/).**

---

**UPDATE:** I've managed to do it with the [transitions plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). One problem remains: when text slides in the box I can see how it enters the box from outside. [Click here](http://www.sopranowebdesign.com/animation/) to see what I mean.

---

I'd like to achieve [this flash effect](http://www.sopranowebdesign.com/animation/) using jQuery (top -> flash, bottom -> jquery) so it would be viewable on iphones and smartphones.

At the moment, I can't get the text to slide in from underneath those boxes.

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="banner">
    <div>
        <img src="img/banner-1.jpg" class="banner-bg" />
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="left-text"><span>POLISHED FLOORS1</span></div>
        <div class="right"></div>   
        <div class="right-text"><span>Custom-made, elegant and long lasting.</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/banner-2.jpg" class="banner-bg" />
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="left-text"><span>POLISHED FLOORS2</span></div>
        <div class="right"></div>   
        <div class="right-text"><span>Custom-made, elegant and long lasting.</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/banner-3.jpg" class="banner-bg" />
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="left-text"><span>POLISHED FLOORS3</span></div>
        <div class="right"></div>   
        <div class="right-text"><span>Custom-made, elegant and long lasting.</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //$("#banner .left").transition({opacity: "1", width: "238px"}, 1200);
    //$("#banner .right").transition({opacity: "0.7", width: "662px"}, 1200);
    //$("#banner .left-text").delay(1200).transition({ opacity: '1', x: '-220px' });
    //$("#banner .right-text").delay(1200).transition({ opacity: '1', x: '+642px' });

    $(function(){
        $ds = $('#banner div .banner-bg');
        $ds.hide().eq(0).show();
        setInterval(function(){
                $ds.filter(':visible').fadeOut(function(){
                        var $banner_bg = $(this).next('div .banner-bg');
                        var $left = $(this).next('div .left');
                        var $right = $(this).next('div .right');
                        var $left_text = $(this).next('div .left-text');
                        var $right_text = $(this).next('div .right-text');
                        if ( $banner_bg.length == 0 ) {
                            $ds.eq(0).fadeIn();
                        } else {
                            $left.transition({opacity: "1", width: "238px"}, 1200);
                            $right.transition({opacity: "0.7", width: "662px"}, 1200);
                            $left_text.delay(1200).transition({ opacity: '1', x: '-220px' });
                            $right_text.delay(1200).transition({ opacity: '1', x: '+642px' });
                            $banner_bg.fadeIn();
                        }
                });
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

**CSS code:**

```
#banner {
    height:299px;
    width:900px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#banner .banner-bg {
    z-index:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#banner .left {
    float:left;
    width:0px;
    height:100px;
    background:url(img/banner-left-bg.png);
    opacity:0.3;
    position:relative;
    z-index:7;
}
#banner .right {
    float:right;
    width:0px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#34515c;
    opacity:0.3;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}
#banner .left-text, #banner .right-text {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial;
    font-size:22px;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#fff;
    top:35px;
}
#banner .left-text {
    position:absolute;
    left:233px;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:8;
}
#banner .right-text {
    position:absolute;
    right:662px;
    width:630px;;
    font-size:24px;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:6;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Although you'll almost done with your custom made jQuery Slider. This [slider](http://www.kyrielles.net/sliderkit/sliderkit_en.html#Demonstrations) has animated captions feature via a plugin of it's own. But +1 for fancy block animated captions that many jQuery Sliders lack these days.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm trying right now to integrate the fadeIn, fadeOut effect between slides.

Comment: Take a look at the jsFiddle I made in my answer. It might be faster to add in any libraries (or activate jQuery UI for .animate) to make quick changes on the fly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PuuEy/2/) of your online markup.

The solution is to have a `z-index` value for the left block of text, i.e. `.left` and `.left-text` so that it covers the incoming animation.

**EDIT:** For your 2nd Update listed in your question, I see your online HTML and online jQuery is a totally different method than what you have listed here. I see where your headed with this but theres a lot missing in your markup everywhere but you are on the right path.

I would suggest to use one of many free slideshow plugins that can be combined with your unique banner-text that has animation. Take a look at [s3Slider DEMO](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html) here. Those **banner text-boxs** can be swapped out for your own **slick version** instead. The **s3Slider** homepage is [HERE](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/).

**STATUS:** Finally, a jsFiddle that re-creates the Flash Effect using a heavily modified s3Slider jQuery plugin that also validates using jsLint. I have a lot of comments in that Demo.

**LINK:**   [**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wJgTx/10/) (Updated 12/26/2012)

For ***inspiration***, here are some [**webkit examples**](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/css3-ads/) of CSS3 Ad's vs Flash Ad's that look the same. Guess which!

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to update the code. I will check out that link. Thanks!!

Comment: After you check out that website link, I updated my SO Answer with a new jsFiddle working example of this particular flash effect.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like `#banner` needs `overflow: hidden;`.